Is there a correspondence between the finite time evolution in the CFT side of AdS/CFT and the AdS side?
Since the CFT side of AdS/CFT is ordinary Quantum Mechanics, we can talk about a Hamiltonian formulation and finite time evolution of states. What does this finite time evolution of states correspond to on the AdS side? As far as I understand, only the asymptotic evolution of states is defined on the AdS side via the sum over worldsheets.
Is there a finite time evolution of strings states that the strings that the evolution of the boundary CFT correspond to? And can we use this to get the Hamiltonian of string evolution?

In how many spacetime dimensions?

@Qmechanic in any of the known cases of AdS/CFT
